# Fermenter screw cap is cracked

Tags: fermentation

I dry-hopped my beer and after a few days, the screw cap of the fermenter cracked. Now I can even smell my beer.

[image]

(Sorry for the quality)

How bad is it? I'm going to bottle today...

Thanks.

**UPD**: I think it's been a few days since it cracked (I could smell it before but with no sign of crack). Not sure when it actually cracked since I was absent for a while :(

Comment: IMHO - Its not really an oxygen related  problem at all. It would be quite feasible to take the cap off and cover the opening with a bung of cotton wool. The only real problem is that if the crack expands your airlock might fall off! A rubber bung with a hole is a viable substitute.

Comment: If it's venting through the airlock you're going to smell the brew either way.  Your dry hop may have created some nucleation to get the air lock moving again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No big deal if you bottle today. You would be very unlucky if your beer spoils with such a small crack for such little time.  You could even repair it temporarily with scotch or duct tape and it would be fine for a few days.

For your next batch, get a new one if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think it's been a few days since it cracked (I could smell it before but with no sign of crack). Not sure when it actually cracked since I was absent :(